# How to find if a point is within a randomly defined rectangle?

Tags: geometry

I need to find if some point *P* is within an axis aligned bounding box given by points *M1* and *M2*. The catch is: *(M1, M2)* may be defined as *(A, D)*, or *(D, A)*, or *(B, C)*, or *(C, B)*, which means I can't simply test if *(M1.x > P.x < M2.x)*, and so on.

The only solution I can think of is redefining the bounding box as *M1'.x = MIN(M1.x, M2.x), M2'.x = MAX(M1.x, M2.x)*, and so on, and then doing the check I described earlier.

Is there any other way to deal with this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing $x_P$ for the $x$ coordinate of $P,$ and so forth, if
$$ (x_{M1} - x_P)(x_P - x_{M2}) > 0$$
then the $x$ coordinate of $P$ is between the  $x$ coordinates of $M_1$ and $M_2.$
Otherwise it isn't.

There is a corresponding formula for the $y$ coordinate.

Comment: Does not work if *M2.x < M1.x*

Comment: Let M1.x=5, M2.x=0, P.x=3. Then M2.x<M1.x, and (M1.x-P.x)(P.x-M2.x)=(5-3)(3-0)=6>0. Do you have a specific example (with numbers) for which the formula gives the wrong answer? Please show it.

Comment: Sorry, your math works just fine, there was an error in my code.

Comment: Understood. I know what that's like!